# Why is there no Internet permission in the web apk coming from PWAs?

Tags: android, google-chrome, permissions, progressive-web-apps

I'm looking into PWAs. When I pulled the web apk automatically generated from the PWA "installed" on the device, I noticed that there were no Internet permission declared. Anyone knows why?

Comment: because this app is just a link to webbrowser?

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/webapk/shell_apk/src/org/chromium/webapk/shell_apk/TransparentLauncherActivity.java